# Counting sequences of numbers in an array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe for a year of data:

```
        lat     lon     date         month  ssta        90th        10th    threshold   year   dayofyear
21680   30.375  273.875 1982-01-01     1    0.995117    1.566498    -1.620501       0   1982        1
21681   30.375  273.875 1982-01-02     1    1.765118    1.566498    -1.620501       1   1982        2
21682   30.375  273.875 1982-01-03     1    2.495117    1.566498    -1.620501       1   1982        3
....
```

I use the following code to count consecutive sequences of days above/below the threshold (1=above, -1=below, 0=between/neither):

```
aok = year['threshold'].values
for i in range(1, len(aok)):
    if aok[i] == 1:
        aok[i] += aok[i - 1]
    if aok[i] == -1:
        aok[i] += aok[i - 1]
```

It yields an array such as the following which summarizes this single year:

```
array([  0,   1,   2,   0,   0,   0,  -1,  -2,  -3,   0,  -1,  -2,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  -1,  -2,  -3,  -4,  -5,
        -6,  -7,  -8,  -9, -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18,
       -19, -20, -21, -22, -23, -24, -25,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  1,
        2,  3,  4,  5,  6,   0,   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,  7])
(shortened for brevity; has a len of 365 )
```

My question is. Is there a way to return the number of sequences that are >=5 and <=-5? I am counting events that are 5 or more consecutive days above/below the threshold. For example, in the array above, I know I can find the max and the min.. I also know I can use *np.count_nonzero(aok >= 5)* to count above-threshold days. I would have a below-average event that lasts 25 days, and two above-average events, one lasting 6 days and the other lasting 7 days.

How could I return this information on separate events, perhaps in list form like [-25, 6, 7]?

**TLDR;** How to count events (ie sequences of numbers >=5 and <=-5 that are separated by 0's) like in the example array above in a form such as [-25, 6, 7]

Comment: you may have to write `for`-loop to check if current value is in sequence with previous values - ie `abs(current - previous) == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're just looking for neighboring values that are more than 5 apart by value?! If so you can just shift the array by 1 and compare like so

```
arr[np.argwhere(np.abs(arr-np.roll(arr,-1)) >= 5)]
```

This almost gives your desired output just as a 3,1 array. If that bothers you
do

```
arr[np.argwhere(np.abs(arr-np.roll(arr,-1)) >= 5)].reshape(-1)
```

instead.

I suspect your first calculation can be numpyfied in a very similar manner but since you didn't ask and didn't provide the raw data (threshold values) I won't say more about it. Maybe a fun numpy exercise to do yourself :).